# how hex file is converting into binary in microcontroller

Tags: embedded, hex, microcontroller

I am new to embedded programming. I am using a compiler to convert source code into hex and I will burn into microcontroller. My question is:  microntroller (all ICs) will support binary numbers only (0 & 1). Then how it is working with hex file?

Answer (score 4):

the software that loads the program/data into the flash reads whatever format it support which may be intel hex, motorola srecord, elf, coff, or a raw binary or other.  and then do the right thing to program the flash with just the relevant ones and zeros.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the PC you are using right now has a processor inside, which works  just like any other microcontroller. You are using it to browse the internet, although it's all "1s and 0s on the inside". And I am presuming your actual firmware doesn't come even close to running what your PC is running at this moment.

> microntroller will support binary numbers only (0 & 1)

Your idea that "microntroller only supports binary numbers (0 & 1)" is a misconception. At it's very low level, yes, microcontroller contains a bunch of transistors, and each of them can store only two states of information (a bit). 
But the reason for this is simply because this is a practical way to physically store one small chunk of data.

If you check the assembly instruction manual for your uC architecture, you will see a large number of instructions operating on different data widths (**bits grouped into 8, 16 or larger chunks**). If your controller is, say, 16-bit, then this will the basic word size for most instructions, and the one that will be the most efficient. When programming in C, this will also be the size of the "special" `int` type which all smaller integral types get expanded to.

In other words, bits are just **building blocks** of your hardware, and most of the time shouldn't even concern you at the firmware level, let alone higher application levels. Compare it to a human life form: human body is made of cells, but is also capable of doing more than a single-cell organism, isn't it?

> i am using compiler to convert source code into hex

Actually, you are using the compiler to create the **machine code** for your particular microcontroller architecture. "Hex", or more precisely [Intel Hex file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX), is just one of several file formats used for storing the machine code into a file, and it's by convenience a plain-text ASCII file which you can easily open in Notepad.

To clarify, let's say you wrote a simple line of C code like this:

```
a = b + c;
```

Your compiler needs to know which architecture you are targeting, in order to convert this to machine code. For a fictional uC architecture, this will first get compiled to the following fictional [assembly language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language):

```c
// compiler decides that a,b,c will be stored at addresses 0x1000, 1004, 1008

mov ax, (0x1004)   // move value from address 0x1004 to accumulator
add ax, (0x1008)   // add value from address 0x1008 to accumulator
mov (0x1000), ax   // move value from accumulator to address 0x1000
```

Each of these instructions has its own [instruction opcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode), which can be found inside the assembly instruction manual. If the instruction operates on one or more parameters, uC will know that the bytes following the instruction are data bytes:

```c
// mov ax, (addr)   --> opcode 0x10
// add ax, (addr)   --> opcode 0x20
// mov (addr), ax   --> opcode 0x30

mov ax, (0x1004)   // 0x10 (0x10 0x04)
add ax, (0x1008)   // 0x20 (0x10 0x08)
mov (0x1000), ax   // 0x30 (0x10 0x00)
```

Now you've got your machine-code, which, written as hex values, becomes:

```
10 10 04 20 10 08 30 10 00
```

And converted to binary becomes:

```
0001000000010000000010000100000...
```

To transfer this to your controller, you will use a file format which your flash uploader knows how to read, which is what Intel Hex is most commonly used for.

Once transferred to your microcontroller, it will be stored as a bunch of bits in its flash memory, but the controller is designed to read these bits in chunks of 8 or more bits, and evaluate them as instruction opcodes or data, depending on the context. For the example above, it will read first 8 bits, and seeing that it's an instruction opcode `0x10` (which takes an additional address parameter), it will read the next two bytes to form the address `0x1004`. It will then execute the instruction and advance the [instruction pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter).

Answer (score 1):

Hex, Decimal, Binary, they are all just ways of representing a number.

AA in hex is the same as 170 in decimal and 10101010 in binary (and 252 or Octal).

The reason the hex representation is used is because it is very convenient when working with microcontrollers as one hex character fits into 1 nibble. Hence F is 1111, FF is 1111 1111 and so fourth.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. The uesr is not asking why hexadecimal notation is used, but how to make it work on their microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks. OK. I was just trying to explain that hex and binary are in fact just a way of writing down the same thing, and the same file could be written in Hex, Binary or any other base for that matter.

Comment: From this answer, I learned that hexadecimal is used due to convince as opposed to some other technical reason, so I find it helpful. I suppose if it's not technically an answer, that would be better as a comment, though I think it's fine as is.